# HTML dynamic elements have different sizes

Tags: jquery, html, css, thymeleaf

I have list that can have up to two levels. The first level represents countries and the second represents states or provinces.

I can dynamically add new countries or states using `jQuery`. When added, these new entries are added to the database, which then are persisted for future searches.

Now, each entry is represented by a `span` and each country or state that is added uses the same structure as their other siblings. The issue is that when created with `jQuery`, although each element have the same clases, these new children are visualized different.

You can find a working example in the following [test platform](https://jsfiddle.net/k1g5v3oz/).

I am using Thymeleaf for the initial load of elements, and this is the code used.

```
<div class="country-container">
    <th:block th:each="country : ${countries}">
        <div class="country-row">
            <span class="father">
                <i class="fa fa-eye child-toggle"></i>
                <textarea class="data" maxlength="50" rows="1" cols="25" th:text="${country.countryPk}"></textarea>
                <p>Cód: </p>
                <textarea class="country-code" maxlength="4" rows="1" cols="4" th:text="${country.countryCode}"></textarea>
                <i class="fa fa-plus-circle add-province"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-minus-circle delete-country"></i>
            </span>
            <div class="child-container">
                <th:block th:each="province : ${country.provinceSet}">
                    <span class="child">
                        <i class="fa fa-minus-circle delete-province"></i>
                        <textarea class="data" rows="1" cols="25" th:text="${province.provinceId.provincePk}"></textarea>
                         <p>Núm: </p>
                         <textarea class="province-number"
                                  maxlength="2"
                                  rows="1"
                                  cols="4" 
                                  th:text="${province.provinceNumber}">
                         </textarea>
                        <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right info-province"></i>
                    </span>
                </th:block>
            </div>
        </div>
    </th:block>
</div>
```

This is my code used in `jQuery` to create a new province or state.

```
// Add a new province container to a country row
$(document).on('click', '.add-province', function() {

    // Span where the province's father country name is located
    var father = $(this).closest('.father');
    // Father country's row
    var countryRow = $(father).closest('.country-row');
    // Provinces' container
    var childContainer = $(father).next('div.child-container');
    var actionContainer = $('<div class="action-holder full-width add-span">');
    var addProvinceButton = $('<button type="button" class="add-province-button extra-small green">Agregar</button>');

    // If there is no child container (div where all the provinces are) we need to add one to the country row
    if(childContainer.length === 0) {
        childContainer = $('<div class="child-container">');
        $(countryRow).append(childContainer);
    }

    // Set up the span where the province will be located at
    var newChild = $('<span class="child">');
    var minusIcon = $('<i class="fa fa-minus-circle delete-province"></i>');
    var textArea = $('<textarea class="data" rows="1" cols="25"></textarea>');
    var textProvinceNumber = $('<textarea class="province-number" maxlength="2" rows="1" cols="4"></textarea>' +
        '</textarea>');

    // Append the elements to our child
    newChild.append(minusIcon);
    newChild.append(textArea);
    newChild.append($('<p>Num: </p>'));
    newChild.append(textProvinceNumber);

    // Append the new child to his father
    childContainer.append(newChild);
    actionContainer.append(addProvinceButton);
    actionContainer.append($('<p class="cancel-text">Cancelar</p>'));
    newChild.append(actionContainer);

    // Focus on the text box of the new province row
    textArea.focus();
});
```

View of the list when initially loaded.

[image]

View of the list after adding a new province.

[image]

View of the HTML structure after adding the province.

[image]

So, my question is, why is it, that even though all children have the same structure, sizes and css styles, they look different?

Comment: Use the DOM inspector to compare a pre-existing row to one you've appended. There will be a difference somewhere, even if it's just the whitespace

Comment: Which specific element varies in size?

Comment: There is none, I already checked quite some time. The only difference is that one is created with jQuery and the other are loaded with Thymeleaf.

Comment: @isherwood as you can see in the last two images, one of the inputs is positioned a bit more to the left. This happens with all the entries created with jQuery.

Comment: create a test platform for tests please, like in https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @EugeneKapustin just did. I added a working example in jsfiddle.

Comment: .table-list-container span.child - remove padding there. The styles of .father and .child are different -that's why you get it all.
check this one, am I understanding you right? https://jsfiddle.net/s5hc2apo/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elements in the row are implicitly using the `display:inline-block`, and in that case white-space that is in the markup between html tags actually makes a difference. The row that is created statically has significant white space, but elements added with jQuery don't have them. These whitespace elements can be clearly seen in the inspector, like in this screenshot

[image: screenshot]

Possible solutions for solving this problem can be found  [here](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)

Comment: Adding each element without a line break did the trick. Weird it works that way. Thanks!